# EF7 DateTime "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've got an ASP.NET Core project on the go and I've added EF7.

It's all working fine using SQL Server on Amazon RDS, except when I add a DateTime field to my model and migrate it to the database.

Then every time after I restart my project and I attempt to get an entity (via DBContext and Linq) I get a really, really nasty exception message. What could it be about the DateTime values that it doesn't like?

Model class:

```
public class Advertiser
{
    // ... Standard constructors go here

    [Key]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class AdvertiserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Advertiser> Advertisers { get; set; }
}
```

Line of code in the Repository class that causes the exception:

```
public Advertiser Find(string key)
{ 
    return Context.Advertisers.Single(x => x.Key == key);
}
```

Two "stacked" exceptions occur, the first:

```
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler[1]
An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer)
```

And the second:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel[13]
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.ValueBuffer
```

Comment: Include your relevant models/code please

Comment: did you have existing data before adding the new date field? perhaps those rows have null values for the date, if so try populating the null rows

Comment: Very good guess, but I tested against that using sample data and by dropping the table in the database in between tests. It didn't seem to be related to the addition of new columns, and there were never any null values to begin with.

Comment: *"a really, really nasty exception message"* I know it's apparently quite nasty, but providing the message in your question would go a long way towards making this question answerable...

Comment: Just added the exceptions back. Alex up there had edited them out. Apparently too nasty... so, a compromise. I just included the relevant parts.

Comment: did you try .Single(x => x.Key.Equals(key))?

Comment: @Kixoka that doesn't change the result. In fact, my experiments show that merely dereferencing Context.Advertisers (for example by iterating through it as a list using a foreach) produces the exception. I don't even need to refer specifically to an individual field of the model class (such as the DateTime).

Answer (score 0):

DateTime in sql have a min value of 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM. As your TargetProperty is not nullable I suppose your entity is being initialized with '0001/01/01 12:00:00 AM' which is the min value for DateTime in the clr and it is out of range, hence the exception you are getting.

You have two options to resolve your issue, one will be to change the migration Up method or the mapping and set the column datatype to DateTime2. The other way is to declare the TargetDate as nullable. Following snippets.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Advertiser>(entity =>
{    
    entity.Property(a => a.TargetDate)
                .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("DateTime2");
});
```

or

```
public DateTime? TargetDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: I feel like you're onto something because the code (and data) works fine the very first run. Then when I stop and re-start the server, the exceptions begin, suggesting that the problem stems from the re-initialization of the code. Adding the ? "operator" to the DateTime type does result in a nullable field in the database, and in fact, automatically the corresponding data type is DateTime2 which is I believe the effect you were looking for. Unfortunately, this does not change the outcome (the same exceptions occur).

Comment: Are you running on OSX or Linux?

Comment: There is a well known bug for mono:  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4012 and https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3637

Comment: I took a look at those bugs and 4012 is similar enough I posted over there for a little bit of extra opinion on the matter. Thanks for the heads up and yes, I's say we're almost certainly looking at a framework bug here. I'll report back with findings.

Comment: 4012 was a duplicate of https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2596. The real problem is that Mono's implementation of SqlClient is buggy and hasn't been given much attention in years.